# Why is my display on the HDTV clipping while using Windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, resolution, lcd

[image]

This is the display on my second 32" screen. The bottom and the other edges seem to be clipping (I've shown the point from where the bottom clips). I am currently using 1360 x 768 as suggested by [this](https://superuser.com/questions/393073/resolution-setting-for-32-inch-lcd-tv-as-a-pc-monitor) question. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TVs usually overscan.

It's a left-over from the old analog broadcast days when the edge of the picture would contain all kinds of non-picture information that would just look like random sparkles if seen on screen. To eliminate the possibility of this spoiling the viewer's enjoyment, the TV overscans - in effect zooms the picture slightly, to prevent these 'sparkly' edges being seen on screen.

It's still considered 'safer' to over rather than under-scan.
It's a TV, not a monitor, true pixel representation isn't the priority.

Overscan itself will be a property of the TV rather than the computer, so you'll have to see if you can discover in the manual if & how to remove the overscan.
If it doesn't have a specific overscan control, it may be hidden as one that claims to be a 'computer monitor' setting, or similar.

I'd also try it at 1080p [1920 x 1080] resolution & see if it's any better. It should at least be crisper, if that's the TV's native resolution.